# Google Analytics V3 API PHP

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get data from my google analytic account. I have done these steps:

1. Turned on API access for Analytic's
2. Created an OAuth2 and server account to access data
3. Added email address (specified in code) to access my analytic's.

I am using the PHP client from here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client (Alpha)

The error that i am receiving is: 
There was an error : - (get) unknown parameter: 'start-date'

Any help would be really appreciated as banging my head against the wall here.

I have included my code below.

`

```
set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

$client_id = 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = 'xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$keyfile = 'xxx-privatekey.p12';
$redirect_url = 'http://xxx/tags/v1.0.0-alpha/examples/analytics.php';
$client_secret = 'xxx';

// Initialise the Google Client object
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Your product name');
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_url);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

$client->setAssertionCredentials(
        new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_account_name,
            array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'),
            file_get_contents($keyfile)
        )
);

// Get this from the Google Console, API Access page
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// We have finished setting up the connection,
// now get some data and output the number of visits this week.

// Your analytics profile id. (Admin -> Profile Settings -> Profile ID)
$analytics_id   = 'ga:xxx';
$lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$today          = date('Y-m-d');

try {
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id, $lastWeek, $today,'ga:visits');
    echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you found an answer to this one on your own but I had this same issue and resolved it by editing the **apiclient/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php** file on lines 93 & 98

```
          "start_date" => array(
              "location" => "query",
              "type" => "string",
              'required' => true,
          ),
            "end_date" => array(
              "location" => "query",
              "type" => "string",
              'required' => true,
          ),
```

needs to become:

> ```
>         "start-date" => array(
>               "location" => "query",
>               "type" => "string",
>               'required' => true,
>           ),
>             "end-date" => array(
>               "location" => "query",
>               "type" => "string",
>               'required' => true,
>           ),
> ```